# Can we email additional participants information to the person who did the registration?

Tags: civievent

We have individuals registering additional participants for events but the additional participants information (which includes custom fields it will be useful for the person doing the registration to have a copy of) is not being emailed to them.

We have considered requiring them to enter an email address for each participant and letting them use their own (by ticking "Same Email Address" in event setup) but the dedupe matching means the details of the subsequent participants entered overwrite the original users registration information.

Is there a way to send the details for the additional participants a person has registered to them in the confirmation email without collecting additional emails for the other participants? If not is there a way to stop the original details being overwritten if the same email address is used for multiple participants so they can receive multiple emails confirming each participants information?

Comment: What version of Civi and what CMS are you using?

Comment: If you are using Drupal, webform civicrm integration can do this job. I'm not sure on wordpress though.

Comment: We are using Wordpress I'm afraid, seems like webform in Drupal would be perfect but the only alternative I can find for Wordpress is Gravity Forms and that requires paying for.